# RxJS error of manipulations while trying to build obj with streams coming from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to build a template driven form with multiple streams coming from Firebase.
But I keep getting errors about

> Converting circular structure to JSON`as soon as I use the`| json pipe.

(I really don't understand this error)

[image]

And also I'm having a hard time building the object the way I need it with RxJS.

**I need someting like this to build the form in the view:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "screens_size",
    "values": ["29-", "30-39", "40-49"]
  },
  {
    "name": "colors",
    "values": ["red", "yellow", "green"]
  }
]
```

**How do I get something like above from what is bellow from firebase.**
Datas are in 2 separate lists in firebase.
its stored like this :

```
{
  "nodes_filters": {
    "$id": {
      "screens_size": true,
      "colors": true
    }
  }
}
```

Used in `nodeService.getNodeFiltersGroups()` and

```
{
  "filters_values": {
    "screens_size": {
      "29-": true,
      "30-39": true,
      "40-49": true
    },
    "colors": {
      "red": true,
      "yellow": true,
      "green": true
    },
  }
}
```

Used in `nodeService.getFilterValues()`

**node.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2";

@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getNodeFiltersGroups(nodeId) {
    return this.db.list('nodes_filters/' + nodeId);
  }

  getFilterValues(filterId, query = {}) {
    return this.db.list('filters_values/' + filterId, query);
  }

}
```

**filters.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {NodeService} from "../node.service";
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'filters',
  templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filters.component.scss']
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {

  public filterTypes$;
  public valuesFilter$;
  public filters = [];
  public filterValues;

  @Input() nodeId;
  @Input() currentFilters;

  constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filterTypes$ = this.nodeService.getNodeFiltersGroups(this.nodeId)
      .map(c => c.map(y => ({"name": y.$key})))
      //  [{"name": "screens_size"}, {"name": "stores"}]

    const filterTypesArray = this.filterTypes$
      .map(x => x.map(y => y.name))
      //  ["screens_size", "stores"]


    this.valuesFilter$ = filterTypesArray
      .do(console.log) //  ["screens_size", "stores"]
      .flatMap(y => y.map(x => this.nodeService.getFilterValues(x, { query: { orderByValue: true, equalTo: 1 } })))
      .do(console.log) //  FirebaseListObservable {_isScalar: false, _ref: U}

  }

}
```

**Edit2 added content bellow**

**filters.component.html**

```
<h2>Filters</h2>

<form #filterForm="ngForm" novalidate>

  {{valuesFilter$ | async | json }}

</form>
```

With all those line I currently get

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./FiltersComponent class FiltersComponent - inline template:10:38 caused by: Converting circular structure to JSON

This error is fixed if I remove the json pipe but I get `[object Object]`

If I try to do it like this

```
<h2>Filters</h2>


<form #filterForm="ngForm" novalidate>

  <ul>

    <li *ngFor="let v of valuesFilter$ | async">
      {{v}}
    </li>

  </ul>

</form>
```

I get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./FiltersComponent class FiltersComponent - inline template:7:8 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

So I guess I'm giving it object instead of array but I don't know how to do that. I'm lost in my RxJS part.

I've been on this for the last 3 days. Any advice will be usefull. If something is not clear, please tell me, I'll try to clarify.

**Edit3: added content bellow**

With forkJoin and @cartant 's solution it's much better and I get the follow  object:

```
[ 
  [ 
    { "$value": 1, "$key": "29-" }, 
    { "$value": 1, "$key": "30-39" }, 
    { "$value": 1, "$key": "40-49" }
  ], 
  [ 
    { "$value": 1, "$key": "red" }, 
    { "$value": 1, "$key": "yellow" } 
  ] 
]
```

But in the view, I need to be able to tell from with filter values comes. So I would need something like this:

```
[ 
  {
    "name": "screens_size",
    "values": [ 
      { "$value": 1, "$key": "29-" }, 
      { "$value": 1, "$key": "30-39" }, 
      { "$value": 1, "$key": "40-49" }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "colors",
    "values": [ 
      { "$value": 1, "$key": "red" }, 
      { "$value": 1, "$key": "yellow" } 
    ]
  }
]
```

The obj is already a bit constructed in filterTypes$.

**Edit1: Update title**
**Edit2: Add filters.component.html file and some explanations**
**Edit3: It works with forkJoin. Adding some details about the needed obj in the view**

Comment: I don't see how you could get a circular structure from Firebase. Are you using the `async` pipe in your HTML template for your observable properties? Perhaps you should include the template in your question, too.

Comment: Hello @cartant and thanks for your help. You are right, I've updated the main post and added filters.component.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `flatMap` is returning an array of observables, so this:

```
this.valuesFilter$ = filterTypesArray
  .do(console.log) //  ["screens_size", "stores"]
  .flatMap(y => y.map(x => this.nodeService.getFilterValues(x, { query: { orderByValue: true, equalTo: 1 } })))
  .do(console.log) //  FirebaseListObservable {_isScalar: false, _ref: U}
```

effects an observable with the type `Observable<FirebaseListObservable<any>>`, as it's the array that's flattened.

When you use the `async` pipe, you get the `FirebaseListObservable` as the result and the 'circular structure' error when it's received by the `json` pipe.

If you want to map the array of filters to filter values, you could use `forkJoin` (which takes an array of observables and returns an observable that emits an array of the last values from those observables):

```
this.valuesFilter$ = filterTypesArray
  .flatMap(types => Observable.forkJoin(
    types.map(type => this.nodeService.getFilterValues(type, {
      query: { orderByValue: true, equalTo: 1 }
    }).first())
  ))
```

Note that `first` is used, as the observables passed to `forkJoin` have to complete.

To return something other than the array of filter values, the optional `forkJoin` selector can be used to combine the filter names and values:

```
this.valuesFilter$ = filterTypesArray
  .flatMap(types => Observable.forkJoin(
    types.map(type => this.nodeService.getFilterValues(type, {
      query: { orderByValue: true, equalTo: 1 }
    }).first()),
    (...results) => types.map((type, index) => ({ name: type, values: results[index] }))
  ));
```

Comment: Great it's working! I've never had this result before. It's going forward again! The final object is missing the name of the filter so that I can use it in the view. Do you know how to do that? I've updated the main post with more details.

Comment: Updated the answer to use a selector to combine the files name/values and to use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: It's working. You are my hero! Thanks 1000x! I though I would never make this one.